# Unhide a gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i am really struggling with an issue: I made a windows form application, that contains a DataGridView which has the property Visible set to "false" as default. I want to unhide it by pressing a button. I tried with DataGridView.Visible = true and didn't work... Any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: if you can show us some code maybe I can help you. For example the event subscribed to the click action

Answer (score 0):

You postback when you press button and if you dont have code for NOT initiate the gridview on postback you just set the default value for gridview to false again. I would try to set the gridview to visible = true in the aspx, then have a Page_load similar to this in the code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myGridView.Visible = false;
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
            myGridView.Visible = true;
        }   
    }
```